# C++ error relating to IXMLDOMNode*

Tags: c++, com, mfc

I'm having trouble compiling one of our legacy COM components.  I get the following compiler error:

```
error C2501: 'IXMLDOMNode' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IXMLDOMNode'
```

On this line of code in a .h file:

```
IXMLDOMNode* CreateChildNodeOfItem(IXMLDOMNode* pNode, DOMNodeType nodeType, CString strName);
```

I assumed IXMLDOMNode was coming from this library:

```
#include <msxml.h>
```

Do I need to install a missing SDK?

**Edit:**

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
//  or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
//      are changed infrequently
//

#if !defined(AFX_STDAFX_H__84FB3EAC_AE73_4076_9DF6_E48B18DA7098__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_STDAFX_H__84FB3EAC_AE73_4076_9DF6_E48B18DA7098__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000

#define VC_EXTRALEAN        // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers

#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
#include <afxdisp.h>        // MFC Automation classes
#include <afxdtctl.h>       // MFC support for Internet Explorer 4 Common Controls
#ifndef _AFX_NO_AFXCMN_SUPPORT
#include <afxcmn.h>         // MFC support for Windows Common Controls
#endif // _AFX_NO_AFXCMN_SUPPORT

#include <atlbase.h>
#include <msxml.h>

//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.

#endif // !defined(AFX_STDAFX_H__84FB3EAC_AE73_4076_9DF6_E48B18DA7098__INCLUDED_)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the way I'm including msxml and it seems to have fixed the compiler errors.  I changed:

```
#include <msxml.h>
```

to

```
#import <msxml.dll> raw_interfaces_only
using namespace MSXML;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should show more context. Perhaps you should qualify

```
MSXML::IXMLDOMDocument
```

See also: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301939 for platform incompatibilities

Comment: I did look at that article and I also tried the fully qualified name but it results in the following:    error C2653: 'MSXML' : is not a class or namespace name

Comment: are you including <msxml.h> _before_ stdafx.h?

Comment: maybe just include a larger snipper/more relevant code. The error C2061 doesn't really make sense IMHO (should be `C2065: undeclared identifier` really if the header file was missing. Is there a macro define that interferes?)

Comment: I'm including <msxml.h> in stdafx.h and then I'm including stdafx.h inside of the header file above.  This is the only include in that header file.  I have posted my stdafx.h above.

Comment: try removing `#define VC_EXTRALEAN` (also, google rumors that you might need MSXML2::, also have you tried `#import "msxml.dll" named_guids raw_interfaces_only` instead of the readymade include?)

Comment: You mean, the removal of VC_EXTRALEAN did not help? I found it here: [`The basic idea is you must had included support for ActiveX and Automation in the AppWizard`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/tbtreestatemgr.aspx?msg=2234369)

Comment: A combination of your comments seemed to fix this.  Please look at the code I changed below.  Thanks for all your help.